# How do I use the PUT feature in REST

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using this git-hub library:
http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver
How do I use the PUT feature to save its data?

```
example: example.com/put/some-data/some-data/...
```

Comment: is using put a bad practice?

Comment: @Exploit - using put is a very bad practice, it's not supported by most browsers

Comment: My purpose is to send data from an external website using curl into this application. Would I be using POST then? if yes, how do i do that?

Comment: If the API uses PUT, you can't use POST. And I don't see how it's relevant that browsers don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this: **but take in count that `PUT` is less commonly used and not supported by most browsers**

```
function somename_put() 
        {  
            $data = array('somedata: '. $this->put('some-data'));  
            $this->response($data);  
        }
```

Comment: thanks, how do i view it in the browser? i tried mysite.com/index.php/example/user_put/somedata and it doesnt work

Comment: @Exploit - are you getting the data. and are you using `cURL` . if so `$this->responce($data)` just for testing should tells you if you are working in the right way. or am I misunderstanding your point here?

Comment: btw, i am sending data from one external website to this rest server via a form. Would I use PUT or POST?

Comment: @Exploit - use post. here's a good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) that might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I read that I dont understand how to do it, if you dont mind can you write an example then how to do a test via the browser

Comment: @Exploit - I really don't mind. but you can't test webservice via browser. it will end with error like `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}` so you need to test it via your post requester.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an ajax request e.g.

(assumes use of jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/my_controller/somedata',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: problem is if you type that url into the browser it wont work. The author has some kind of routing going on that I dont see setup in the routes file.

Comment: No, if typed into the address bar, the browser will issue a GET request. You need to issue a PUT HTTP request. An easy way to do this in the browser is using an ajax request, but with the type specifically set to PUT. I believe Phil Sturgeon's REST library looks at the HTTP request type issued (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) and routes to the relevant controller method.

Answer (score 0):

According this (link: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L915), `$this->put` only return if passed a param to it (so that works: `$username = $this->put('username')`). But in `REST_Controller`, `$this->_put_args` is protected so, you will extend this class and can access it like: `$params = $this->_put_args`.

In short (this is just an example, you may improve it as you need);

```
<?php
// route: /api/users/123
class Users extends REST_Controller
{
    ...

    // update a user's data
    public function user_put() {
        $params = $this->_put_args;

        // you need sanitize input here, "db" is a pseudo
        $username = $db->escape($params['username']);
        $userpass = $db->escape($params['userpass']);

        $db->update(array(
            'username' => $username,
            'userpass' => $userpass
        ), (int) $params['id']);

        if (!$db->error) {
            // suppose right code should be 201 for PUT
            $this->response('Created', 201);
        } else {
            $this->response('Internal Server Error', 500);
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
// Some ajax library
Ajax("/api/users/123", {
    method: "PUT",
    data: {username:"John", userpass:"new pass"},
    onSuccess: function(){ console.log("Success!"); }
    ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: And more examples here: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/controllers/api/example.php